# Function that adds numbers of the list are divisible by 3,4 but not by 6

Tags: function, haskell

Write a function sumdv that holds a list of integers and adds up all numbers in the list that are divisible by 3 or 4 but not by 6. The functions sum, filter, convolutions and list generators are forbidden.

```
sumdv :: [Integer] -> [a] -> [Integer]
sumdv = add
sumdv [] = 0
sumdv (x:xs) 
    | mod 3 x == 0 || mod 4 x == 0 = x + sumdv (x:xs)
    | mod 6 x == 0 = sumdv (x:xs)
```

Hey guys again, I´m a little bit confused about the right type, because the system shows only "Variable not in scope: sumdv :: [Integer] -> t". My thoughs are that at first I have a list with Integer, because of the fact that it must be "whole numbers" then the gave me a list of different elements that must be add together for me it is: [Integer] -> [a] -> a but it didnt work :( –

Comment: the function should named sumdv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that there are multiple mistakes:

- type is wrong (based on the description you should accept collection of elements and return one)
- seems like `sumdv = add` should be just removed
- `sumdv (x:xs)` calls lead to infinite recursion (you are calling function passing the same input without modification)
- [`mod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) arguments are in the wrong order
- `mod x 6 == 0` pattern guard should be before `mod x 3 == 0 || mod x 4 == 0` because only first matching guard is evaluated, and you will not filter out number divisible by 6 if `mod x 3 == 0` is placed first
- you are missing pattern guard for `otherwise` case (when number is not divisible by 3,4 or 6)

Taking in account all the notes above sample implementation can look like this:

```hs
sumdv [] = 0
sumdv (x:xs)
    | mod x 6 == 0                  = sumdv (xs) 
    | mod x 3 == 0 || mod x 4 == 0  = x + sumdv (xs)
    | otherwise                     = sumdv (xs)
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much, it is nice that my teacher das that the Order is not important, But Good to know ;)

Comment: Your answer also has multiple definitions of `sumdv`. That's OK. The problems with `sumdv = add` are 1) It use a different number of arguments than the other two, and 2) if the first point wasn't a problem, this would catch all possible cases, rendering the other definitions moot.

Comment: Just for funsies (don't do this, it is unreadable): `sumdv (x:xs) | (mod x 3 == 0) /= (mod x 4 == 0) = x + sumdv xs | otherwise = sumdv xs`

Comment: @DanielWagner When `x` is 6, `mod x 3 == 0` is `True` while `mod x 4 == 0` is `False`, so it looks like your version of `sumdv` would take `[6]` to 6, no?  I think a better "unreadable" version would be: `sumdv (x:xs) = sumdv xs + if mod (mod x 12) 5 > 2 then x else 0`